# How to add widget to the header.php in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i have installled a pludgin whose named is `Translator Box` , i using its short code and put it into my wordpress theme header.php.

```
 [translation_box languages="english,russian,german,spanish,french,chinese" width="100%" height="200px" bgcolor="white" txtcolor="#000000"]
```

but is doesn't work!

it also generate a widget at Enabled widget in the widgets part. is there a way when using some code in header.php that can invoke the widget? thank you.

Answer (score 16):

You can define a part in your header.php to show widgets.
In your functions.php make something like this:

```
function my_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'your-theme' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>",
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Header Area', 'your-theme' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-2',
    'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site header', 'your-theme' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="headwidget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>",
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init' );
```

The first part for example will be your widget area in the sidebar and the second your widget area in your header.

Now include in your header.php file:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

where your widget should be.

In your admin interface you should now have 2 areas ('Main Sidebar' and 'Header Area') you can fill with widgets.

Answer (score 2):

use [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>
```

Comment: is there a way how to find out the pludgin shortcode? thank u

Comment: Most plugins will have the shortcode in their documentation. If not, you can look through the plugin's PHP files for "add_shortcode". The format will be add_shortcode( 'short_code_name', 'function_name' ).